# Passing parameters using call by name

Tags: c++, parameters

Let's say I have this C++ like snippet:

```
int A[3] = {0, 2, 1};

void f(int x, int y) {
    x++; A[1]--; y++;
    print(x, y, A[0], A[1], A[2]);
}

void main() {
    f(A[0], A[A[1]]);
    print(A[0], A[1], A[2]);
}
```

I would like to pass `A[0]` and `A[A[1]]` in `f()` using call by-name.

In a situation like this, the results printed are supposed to be: `1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1` (This is from a programming languages class given by our teacher). However, I cannot understand how `y` can be 1 in `f`'s call to `print()`. Isn't `y` binded with `A[A[1]]=A[2]=1` at start and after `A[1]--` change to `A[A[1]]=A[1]=1`?After that, `y++` won't make `y` equal to 2?

Moreover, in order for `A[1]` to be 2 after `A[1]--`, it has to be incremented somehow by 1, and that is exactly what `y++` does, meaning `y++=A[1]++=2`. So, in `f`'s call to `print()`, `y =/= A[1]`?

Comment: C++ doesn't support call-by-name. Do you mean call-by-value?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I know it is hypothetical.The code is supposed to be C++ like and i did not know what tag to give

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 Please elaborate. Asking about _hypothetical_ features isn't useful.

Comment: Then you should choose a language with call-by-name support. Call-by-name means that you pass statements and not values. The statements are lazy evaluated in the function, not at the function call.

Comment: I'm not even sure how assignment to a call-by-name argument would *hypothetically* work. The languages I know of that can do call-by-name stuff are Haskell (kind of) and Scala, and in both of those, CBN arguments are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to pass by name would be to pass functor instead of single (int) parameters:

So, something like:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
void f(X x, Y y) { // or void f(std::function<int&()> x, std::function<int&()> y)
    x()++; A[1]--; y()++;
    print(x, y, A[0], A[1], A[2]);
}

int main() {
    f([]() -> int&{ return A[0];}, []() -> int&{ return A[A[1]];});
    print(A[0], A[1], A[2]);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VRSUn5)

An ugly alternative is MACRO:

```
#define f(x, y) do { (x)++; A[1]--; (y)++; print((x), (y), A[0], A[1], A[2]); } while (0)

int main() {
    f(A[0], A[A[1]]);
    print(A[0], A[1], A[2]);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/UId6UV)

Comment: I mean, it works, but it's far more messy than simply passing by reference.

Comment: @Chipster: Whereas passing `A[0]` by reference would be enough, `A[A[1]]` depends of (mutable) intermediate value of `A[1]`, so reference won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why shouldn't it work? `A[1] = 2`, so shouldn't `A[A[1]]` result in passing `A[2]` y reference?

Comment: @Chipster: but OP wants that if `A[1]` is modified inside the function (with said 0), it is not longer `A[2]` but `A[0]` (as `A[A[1]]` is now `A[0]`). An ugly alternative would be to use MACRO: `#define f(x, y) do { (x)++; A[1]--; (y)++; print((x), (y), A[0], A[1], A[2]); } while (0)`.

Answer (score 6):

When you pass a value to a function in C++, it becomes an independent value and it does not refer to the array any more. Because of this, `y` equals 1 in the function and it acts independently from `A['1']`.

Comment: That's a comment at best.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `x` and `y` are **passed by value**, which means *copies* of the values are being made. Inside of `f()`, `x` and `y` are treated as local variables, and any changes made to `x` and `y` are not reflected back to the caller. If you want that, you need to **pass by reference** instead:

```
void f(int &x, int &y)
```